# using eval inside of make function

Tags: debugging, makefile, gnu-make

(Note -- this is similar to my previous question, but it seems to have a different cause, so I'm posting a new question here).

I'm debugging some makefiles which are littered with some very convoluted eval's.   I'd like to be able to accurately dump what the eval's are expanding to, and then call the evals.   I need to do this such that I can easily turn on/off the debugging, but I'm finding some odd behaviour with `eval` from within a function.  I have:

```
FOO := a:=foo
$(eval $(FOO))
$(info a=$(a))   #a=foo -- OK

define eval_dbg
$(info eval_dbg: running [$1]) # $1 is "a:=bar"
$(eval $(1))                   # fails - missing seperator...
endef

$(call eval_dbg,a:=bar)    #causes error...
$(info a=$a)
```

But, I get:

```
a=foo
eval_dbg: running [a:=bar]
test2.mk:17: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Is it possible to eval a call parameter?

---

** minimal reproducable example: **

```
tmp> more test3.mk
FOO := a:=foo
$(eval $(FOO))
$(info a=$(a))

define eval_dbg
$(info eval_dbg: running [$1])
$(eval $(1))
endef

$(call eval_dbg,a:=bar)
$(info a=$a)

all:
        @echo running $@

tmp> make -f test3.mk
a=foo
eval_dbg: running [a:=bar]
test3.mk:10: *** missing separator.  Stop.

tmp> make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: How are you stuck with 3.81? Maybe we can help with this - I don't know why 3.81 is still so popular, its incompatibilities come up every 3 weeks or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the result of a call to `eval(...)` is the empty string, so in effect you are passing `call` an argument -- the defined function `eval_dbg` -- that contains whitespace, and `call` doesn't like whitespace.

```
define func_1
$(info hello)
endef

$(call func_1) # this works                                                     

define func_2
$(info hello)

endef

$(call func_2) # this fails 

define func_3
$(info hello)
$(eval a:=b)
endef

$(call func_3) # this also fails
```

But there's no reason to call `eval` from within the function. As you've shown, you can print the statement and then call `eval` on it. Or you can pass `eval` the result of a call to `call`:

```
define foo_double
$(1):=foo_$(1)$(1)
endef

$(info $(call foo_double,a))
$(eval $(call foo_double,a))

$(info a is $a)
```

Comment: `call doesn't like whitespace` Call is ok with whitespace. It even preserves it (for the most part). That might be the problem for a caller, but not for a call.

Comment: Can you expand on `call doesn't like whitespace`?   From my understanding `$(info)` also results in an empty string, so why does `func_1` work, and not `func_2`?       Unfortunately, the real life scenario is considerably more complicated than what I posted (this was just a minimal example), where there's 58 evals, most of which are inside of for loops, and most of which have multi-line expressions.   I was really hoping for a drop-in replacement for eval that would print the expression before evaluating it (if debugging is on of course...).

Comment: @user11809993 `func_1` expands to an empty string; `func_2` expands into a single newline.

Comment: @user11809993 That's because _one_ newline after `define` and another _one_ before `endef` are automatically deleted.

Comment: _I was really hoping for a drop-in replacement for eval that would print the expression before evaluating it_ : Simplest thing is to replace the `eval` with `error`. The arguments will appear on stderr and _make_ will stop.

Comment: On 4.2.1 the examples work correctly - as they should.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to **comments** inside "define".

Basically, "define" is the same as variable assignment (except newlines). "Call" does expansion, but not evaluation. Hence the comments got into stream without being evaluated --> error occurs!

So the moral:

1. Define is not a macro; it's a string
2. Call is not an evaluation; it's an expansion
3. Comments are not whitespace; they are evaluated

UPD. As it turns out another problem is an old make version. It looks that v3.81 cannot simply ignore whitespace, as modern make versions do.

An additional eval fixes this issue:

```
$(eval $(call eval_dbg,a:=bar))
```

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Unfortunately if I remove the comments I still get an error.  (In fact the error with the comments is different than the one I described -- my bad I added the comments while writing the post for clarity, not realizing they changed behavior).

Comment: @user11809993 I don't have an error if comments are removed. What is [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Added the MRE to my question (raw output, cut and paste -- added a couple of newlines between commands for clarity).   I'm starting to get the feeling you're running a different version of make.   Does @Beta's `func_1` and `func_2` work on your make?  (`func_2` fails on mine)

Comment: @user11809993 Ver 3.81 is severely outdated. It looks that it wants to eval whitespace too. This is something not encountered in modern make versions.

Comment: Ahh.   Unfortunately, I'm stuck with 3.81...   I did find a workaround though based on your comments -- I simply put the `$(info $(1))$(eval $(1))` on the same line, and it's happy!

Comment: Appologizing -- technically, Beta's answer is correct, so I'm giving him credit for the answer.   I also unfortunately do not have enough rep to upvote, so I can't upvote your answer as useful as it was.   I do appreciate your time though.